# Android Notification - Non Activity Class

Tags: android, accelerometer

I have a class that extends SensorEventListener and when I override onSensorChanged I want to fire a notification based on a certain sensor value.  I've had problems understanding how the NotificationManager works since I assume you can only implement notifications within an Activity class if I am correct?  How would I trigger a simple notification based on a sensor value contained within a class that isn't an activity?

Comment: You can send a notification from a service.

Comment: Not exactly your answer but this tut triggers a notification from a service: http://blog.blundell-apps.com/notification-for-a-user-chosen-time/

Answer (score 1):

> I've had problems understanding how the NotificationManager works since I assume you can only implement notifications within an Activity class if I am correct?

You are not correct. However, the sensor framework is primarily designed to be used by an activity, so hopefully that is how you are using it, and therefore you would have an activity around to raise the `Notification`.

> How would I trigger a simple notification based on a sensor value contained within a class that isn't an activity?

It is the responsibility of some `Context` to raise the `Notification`. That could be an activity, or a service, or the `Context` supplied to a `BroadcastReceiver`, etc.. You use this `Context` to get the `NotificationManager` via a call to `getSystemService()`. Whether the `SensorEventListener` holds a `NotificationManager`, or whether the `SensorEventListener` lets, say, your `Activity` know about the event (so it can raise the `Notification`), is largely up to you.